# Utility that lets you minimize windows store apps to tray

Tags: windows

I'm looking for software that can make Windows new UI apps (they were called Metro before I don't know what they are called now) minimizable to tray. Example of an app that can't minimize to tray is WhatsApp.

I don't want to use ExtraButtons.

Any other programs that might work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to make an account just to reply to this. I've been using one for the longest time called 'WhatsApp Tray' that can be found on GitHub. Recently however, Whatsapp updated their app and removed all downloads to their non UWP (I'm assuming) app, thus *forcing* you to download from the Windows Store. Unfortunately it means the old app, which was working till yesterday, just stopped working and was stuck in an infinite loading loop whilst screaming at me to update. As you might have figured, the 'WhatsApp Tray' app which hasn't been updated since Jan 2022, just doesn't work with this new version.

Thankfully! If you're still looking for something to minimize whatsapp to tray (doesn't work on startup as of yet, unlike the old one) there are alternatives available that I've found. They are the following:

- [RBTray](https://github.com/benbuck/rbtray)
- [MinimizeToTray](https://github.com/sandwichdoge/MinimizeToTray)
- [Traymond](https://github.com/fcFn/traymond)
- [Portable HideWin](https://www.softpedia.com/get/PORTABLE-SOFTWARE/System/System-Enhancements/Windows-Portable-Applications-Portable-HideWin.shtml)
- [KSTray](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/KSTray.shtml)

I've tried out RBTray and PortableHideWin, and while both are good, they're not quite what WhatsappTray was. I haven't tried MinimizeToTray, Traymond, or KSTray, so if you end up trying each one, tell me which is the better of 'em will ya.

Comment: I use one of those multi messenger programs now .. ferdium.. it is pretty good.. except spotify won't run, and you can't open new tabs within it. What's app shows a reload banner some times but still works even when the banner is showing. I love the program because now I don't need whatsapp and several other programs installed (slack, messenger) on my computer .. also you can silence all notifiations from all these apps just from right clicking its context menu

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).